# Приложение React Native распознаётся как игра на Samsung Note8

Tags: react-native, samsung

Всем привет!

Написал приложение на React Native. Приложение несложное, больше информационное, используется Redux, Saga, несколько прилинкованных npm пакетов. Запускается и работает в обычном режиме, не полноэкранном. Структура приложения была построена на базе тулзы Ignite.

Суть проблемы в том, что у заказчика на телефоне (Samsung Note8) приложение определяется как игра. Например, на экране блокировке отображается надпись, что запущена игра. Во время работы приложения появляются дополнительные кнопки геймпада или что-то вроде этого.

Самому потестить нет возможности, данным телефоном не пользовался вообще. Не могу пронять даже в какую сторону копать или как сформулировать проблему точнее, хоть погуглить на худой конец. Нарыл по теме только про Game Tools в последних моделях самсунгов, но не вижу связи с React Native.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

UPDATE:

При более детальном рассмотрении добавилось ещё то, что появляется отступ довольно заметный сверху и чуть меньше снизу, как-будто приложение само имеет внутренние отсупы, развёрнуто не на весь экран или имеет пустой хэдер.  Такой же визуальный эффект есть и у некоторых игр. Дело, по-видимому, действительно в этом самом Game Tools, но информации по подобным проблемам крайне мало. Буду рад за любую помощь или хотя бы направление.

Answer (score 0):

Скажите своему клиенту чтобы отключил Game Tools

[например так](https://www.androidauthority.com/samsung-galaxy-s8-game-launcher-ads-marketing-disable-779504/)

Comment: А если он им пользуется? Неужели со стороны приложения никак не решить, только глобально?

Comment: Такую версию я предлагал. Парирует тем, что на других приложениях подобное не случается. Только, дескать, на этом.